# Is auto renewable subscriptions restricted only to Newsstand?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm trying to find an official doc, where will be proof of restricting auto renewable subscriptions in In App Purchase only to Newsstand apps. Is it true or I can offer premium membership in my app as a monthly auto renewing subscription? In most articles/guides I've found only "is mainly/usually used for Newsstand", but no definite statement. Can anyone point me to appropiate doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/subscriptions.html) official doc by apple, no there aren't restricted only to Newsstand. You can add auto-renewable subscriptions in an app too. Newsstand is not even mentioned in this page.

Comment: True. But phrasing is strongly about content-based: "You can now offer an easy one-click experience for auto-renewable digital subscriptions in your iOS ***content-based*** apps on the App Store. Auto-renewable subscriptions allow users to purchase ***in-app content***, and the purchase is automatically renewed". Any other reassurances?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's totally possible.

An example, the Tab Pro HD iPad app has a monthly subscription, you can only use the app if you have subscribed for that month.

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tab-pro-hd-largest-catalog/id535076358?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

May be helpful but contradict to above answers
http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions reference 
from http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial.